# scp command silently does nothing

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, scp, amazon-web-services

I need to copy a file from my local machine to Amazon AWS Ubuntu machine.

First I tried just this:

```
scp -i learndeepai.pem sb_code.zip ubuntu@34.211.158.***
```

As soon as I execute this, nothing special happens, no errors, I am returned to the command line again, so obviously no upload has happened. The instance is running when I trying to run this command, so it should be able to connect to it.

I then tried this:

```
pscp scp -i learndeepai.pem sb_code.zip ubuntu@34.211.158.***
```

and got response this time:

```
More than one remote source not supported
```

How can I upload my zip file to my AWS instance, seems nothing works. I am on Windows 10 and have PuTTY and `scp` installed.

I'm using http://cmder.net/ as my console

Answer (score 8):

You are missing a colon (`:`) after the "target" argument:

```
scp -i learndeepai.pem sb_code.zip ubuntu@34.211.158.***:
```

Without the colon, the command is an equivalent to `cp`, so it copies `learndeepai.pem` to a *local file* `ubuntu@34.211.158.***`.

---

Thanks to `pscp`, which does not support the (useless) local copy function, you easily learn that, as it says:

```
C:\>pscp -i learndeepai.pem sb_code.zip ubuntu@34.211.158.***
Local to local copy not supported
```